# Is there a better way to do this in python? I am trying to parse Windows 'systeminfo' command

Tags: python, windows

This is the code that I currently have that pulls out the processors from the 'systeminfo' command in windows.
I am looking for a more pythonic way of doing this.

Results is a list of lines from systeminfo split by '\r\n'

Thanks in advance!

```
processor_index = [i for i, s in enumerate(result) if 'processor(s)' in s.lower()]
processor_number = ''.join(result[processor_index[0]]).split(':')[1].lstrip().strip(' ')[0]
print ('processors = '+ str(processor_number))

processors = ''
for i in range(1, int(processor_number)+1):
    processors += str(result[int(processor_index[0])+i]).lstrip()+','

print (processors[:-1])
```

EDIT:
Thank you for the responses, very helpful :)
Is there a way to get the BIOS version as well, because this is the main reason why I need the systeminfo command.
I am doing the same thing with the output of the 'systeminfo' command to get this BIOS version.

Comment: The BIOS version strings can be obtained from the registry, e.g. `import winreg;` `key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'Hardware\Description\System');` `bios_version_strings = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, 'SystemBiosVersion')[0]`.

Comment: I got another way, thanks! I'll post it here for more people when I get to work tomorrow

Comment: Another way is via the WMI `Win32_BIOS` class used via Python's `wmi` module or the command-line program wmic.exe. But it's all the same, ultimately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the various goodies for Windows, including Win32.

```
>>> import win32api
>>> win32api.GetSystemInfo()
(9, 4096, 65536, 140737488289791, 15, 4, 8664, 65536, (6, 14857))
```

The documentation for this one:

```
Return Value
The return value is a tuple of 9 values, which corresponds to the Win32 SYSTEM_INFO structure. The element names are: 
wProcessorArchitecture
dwPageSize
lpMinimumApplicationAddress
lpMaximumApplicationAddress
dwActiveProcessorMask
dwNumberOfProcessors
dwProcessorType
dwAllocationGranularity
(wProcessorLevel,wProcessorRevision)
```

Comment: At the cost of making an obvious statement, this is Windows-specific. OP, this will likely be the best and most complete route if you're using Windows. If you're looking for more general information and may end up using multiple operating systems, one of the more generic options is probably a better bet.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of options based on what information you need

```
import platform
platform.processor()
# returns 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel' on my PC
platform.machine()
# 'AMD64'
platform.architecture()
# ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')

import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.cpu_count()
# 16

import psutil
psutil.cpu_count()
# 16
psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)
# 8
```